# set_format callback in gstreamer

Tags: callback, function-pointers, gstreamer

Can anybody explain me something about `set_format()` callback in gstreamer?

Will this function invoked if any of the pad properties changes? Will this callback happens after each frame processing? When will it be invoked? Is this dependent on `reset()` callback of gstreamer? When will this `reset()` callback happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The set_format is the gstreamer callback function. This will be invoked by the gstreamer whenever the pad property of the plugin gets modified. Suppose if you take example of gstreamer encoder plugin, whenever pad property of encoder(width, height or frame rate) gets changed then set_format callback will be invoked to inform encoder about the changes. so that encoder will modify its state accordingly.